# ASP.NET Core - Custom model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC when we post a model to an action we do the following in order to validate the model against the data annotation of that model:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

If we mark a property as [Required], the ModelState.IsValid will validate that property if contains a value or not.

My question: How can I manually build and run custom validator?

P.S. I am talking about backend validator only.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In .NET Core, you can simply create a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute`. You can see the full details in the ASP.NET Core MVC [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation).

Here's the example taken straight from the docs:

```
public class ClassicMovieAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _year;

    public ClassicMovieAttribute(int Year)
    {
        _year = Year;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        Movie movie = (Movie)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if (movie.Genre == Genre.Classic && movie.ReleaseDate.Year > _year)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I've adapted the example to exclude client-side validation, as requested in your question.

In order to use this new attribute (again, taken from the docs), you need to add it to the relevant field:

```
[ClassicMovie(1960)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Here's another, simpler example for ensuring that a value is `true`:

```
public class EnforceTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public EnforceTrueAttribute()
        : base("The {0} field must be true.") { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) =>
        value is bool valueAsBool && valueAsBool;
}
```

This is applied in the same way:

```
[EnforceTrue]
public bool ThisShouldBeTrue { get; set; }
```

**Edit:** Front-End Code as requested:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

The options are All, ModelOnly or None.

Comment: Could you add the front end code as well? It would help me and other readers I suspect.

Comment: The full example with the client-side implementation is available in the docs, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-client-side-validation).

Comment: I got a question about, because I hace done exactly like you, but, on the client side never validate my customs things

Comment: @sgrysoft This answer doesn't cover client-side validation. I linked above to the docs that explains how to do that. If you're having problems, ask a new question and feel free to post a link to it here.

Answer (score 12):

To create a custom validation attribute in `.Net Core`, you need to inherit from `IModelValidator` and implement `Validate` method.

## Custom validator

```
public class ValidUrlAttribute : Attribute, IModelValidator
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(ModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var url = context.Model as string;
        if (url != null && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
        }

        return new List<ModelValidationResult>
        {
            new ModelValidationResult(context.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, ErrorMessage)
        };
    }
}
```

## The model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidUrl]
    public string ProductThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
}
```

> Will this approach give opportunity to work with "ModelState.IsValid" property in controller action method?

Yes! The `ModelState` object will correctly reflect the errors.

> Can this approach be applied to the model class? Or it can be used with model class properties only?

I don't know if that could be applied onto class level. I know you can get the information about the class from `ModelValidationContext` though:

- `context.Model`: returns the property value that is to be validated
- `context.Container`: returns the object that contains the property
- `context.ActionContext`: provides context data and describes the action method that processes the request
- `context.ModelMetadata`: describes the model class that is being validated in detail

## Notes:

This validation attribute doesn't work with Client Validation, as requested in OP.

Comment: Is it possible to assign values to property values during this validation? Is it a good idea?

Comment: I've already deleted this sample code so I don't have access to a running code and prove you can assign values to properties. I don't think that's a good idea anyway because of single responsibility principle?